# How to update bootstrap tag-input using ngModel in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to update the BootStrap tag-inputs. Inserting and Retrieving the keywords in tag inputs works fine, but when I try to edit and update the keywords it is not updating. Here I used to check in console.log() in ts.

**My TypeScript File**

```
all_prod_keywords;
keyword=["Mobiles","Mixers","Grinders","Tvs","Refrigerators"]

Product_update(id) {
console.log(this.all_prod_keywords)
}
```

**My Html**

```
<form class="auto-com">
                  <div *ngFor="let all_prod_keywords of x.product_tags">
                      <tag-input name="items" [(ngModel)]="all_prod_keywords">
                          <tag-input-dropdown
                          [autocompleteItems]="keyword"
                          [showDropdownIfEmpty]="false"
                          [dynamicUpdate]="false"
                          [appendToBody]="false">
                        </tag-input-dropdown>
                      </tag-input>
              </div>
            </form>

<input type="button" value="update" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="Product_update(x._id)">
```

Comment: which bootstrap library are you using with angular?

Comment: what is the error? Paste the code that is causing issues.

Comment: There is no error but it shows undefined. I am printing console.log(this.all_prod_keywords). What i updated that keywords need to show in console.

Comment: I used this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips.